# CSS Selector - Make all title capitalize

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hei, I have a question. How can we change the title style for element we want? Example like this :

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#!" title="instagram link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" title="facebook link"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" title="linkedin link"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" title="twitter link"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to make all `title` on `<a href="link.com"></a>` tag capital using css `text-transform: capitalize;`

Can we do that?

Comment: no you cannot ... CSS cannot change HTML

Comment: title is an attribute you cannot styling attribute with css

Comment: @TemaniAfif okay, I'm get it :)

Comment: the only way to do is JS, if you are intrested i can show you

Comment: I'm interested, please tell me how @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it with CSS but here is a small JS script to transform your titles:

```js
var e = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a');
for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++) {
  e[i].setAttribute('title',e[i].getAttribute('title').replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase()))
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#!" title="instagram link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" title="facebook link"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" title="linkedin link"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" title="twitter link"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but there is a way to style this.

```
 a[title]{ text-transform: uppercase; }
```

You can also use this for more exact styling:

```
a[href*="example"]{ text-transform: uppercase; }
```

This will select all url with the attribute href, and also have the word example in it. You could use this for your example.

```css
a{ color: red; }
a[title]{ color: blue; }
a[title*="hi"]{ color: green; }
a[title="hi"]{ color: purple; }
```

```html
<a title="hi">Hi</a>
<a title="hi there">Hi</a>
<a title="there">Hi</a>
<a>Hi</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I mean make the title uppercase. Not select the element with attribute (title) selector

Comment: Then Javascript is the only solution I guess